# I have been doing some coding on android's SQLITE Database , how to write Where clause statement in DatabaseHelper.java

Tags: java, android

This is the code , How to Write  Where clause in it.

```
public Cursor getallData3()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res1 = db1.rawQuery("select  *from  "+ TABLE_NAME2    ,null);
        return res1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify your query as

```
"Select * from " + tableName + " where columnName=\"someValue\"";
```